# php: Call to undefined function mcrypt_get_block_size()

Tags: php, undefined, mcrypt

I have installed the McRypt and configure php.ini.
But mcrypt_get_block_size () still doesn't work.
But in PHP - r can be executed correctly mcrypt_get_block_size ().
Did somebody in this situation.

[image]

Comment: mcrypt is abandon-ware, it has not been updated in many years, it is best to move onto a library that is currently supported. Also the Bozos who wrote mcrypt did not support standard PKCS#5 or PKCS#7 padding.

Comment: [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) is a good solution as is [RNCryptor-php](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-php).

Comment: The emphasis now is on why I can run mcrypt_get_block_size in "php- r"
Run the PHP file could not be found in this function.My English is not good. Do you understand.

Answer (score 0):

From the mcrypt {documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.ciphers.php) the proper MCRYPT_ciphername is `MCRYPT_3DES`.

So the call should be:

```
mcrypt_get_block_size('MCRYPT_3DES', 'ecb')
```